# $x-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$ has no solution in $(0,1)$.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, numerical-methods

I have to solve the following exercise: show that $x-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$ has no solution in $(0,1)$.

With the graphic method, it is ok. But is there another proof?

Comment: I see no equation !

Comment: i think he/she meant $$x-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)=0$$

Comment: Using the fact that $x - \sin( \frac{ \pi}{2} x) < 0$, an equivalent statement to this is to prove that $x < \sin( \frac{ \pi}{2} x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll prove that $x-\sin\frac{\pi x}{2}<0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$.

Indeed, let $f(x)=x-\sin\frac{\pi x}{2}$.

Thus, $f''(x)>0$, which says that $f$ is a convex function and from here:
$$f(x)<\max\{f(0),f(1)\}=0$$
and we are done!

Comment: This solution requires knowing that $0 = \sin( \frac{ \pi}{2} * 0)$ and $1 = \sin( \frac{ \pi}{2} * 1)$, but apart from that, your solution is brilliant!

Comment: Why $f(x)<\max (f(0),f(1))$?

Comment: @TheWanderer Because a convex function gets on $[a,b]$ a maximal value or for $x=a$ or for $x=b$, In our case we have $(a,b)$, which says that the maximum does not occur.

Comment: Because the second derivative test shows that the graph points down between $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, so all values from $0$ to $1$ are negative and hence less than $0$.